# Adding test visualizer to existing test in testcomple

Tags: testcomplete

I am new to TestComplete and I use that to create tests. There is a test suite which has already being written by someone else. The tests there do not contain pictures in them. When I run the tests, they pass without problem. Now I want to add visualizer to the existing ones. If I add new tests to the test suite, I can enable test visualizer and do that. But I want to add pictures to the existing ones too. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Open your project, select the *Tools | Current Project Properties* menu item, select the **Visuzlizer** option group and set the **Capture images only** value for the **Collect Test Visualizer data during test run** option.